# How to use relations in Kibi, when creating a visualisation?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, siren

**BACKGROUND** 
After moving our MSSQL DB to an ELK stack version 5.2, we realised we needed a relatiopnal visauliser. By then downgrading to 2.4.1 we were able to link Kibi.

**TRIED**
I have created the relations *between* the tables as shown below;
[image]

[image]

However, when trying to build a simple line graph to compare the tables *tblaccounts* and *aspnetusers* , it simply uses the values in *tblaccountusers*. None of the Kibi documentation seems to help, from what I have seen.

**THE PROBLEM** 
The problem with this is I need the actual values to be used from both tables, through the child table of tblaccountusers, as to display account names rather than the ID number such as 1,2... etc.
If anyone has any guidance or links to help with this, please comment below.